# RTO, Azure SQL DB, 1Hour?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am going through [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity) to try to understand how a geo replicated DB would fit into our RTO and RPO and I was surprised to see RTO of 1H.  I am even more confused as it says the RTO is equal to 1H.  How can that be equal, shouldn't it be less that an hours?

[image]

- So does anyone know why it is so high?  Is it just because Microsoft
  is being safe and in reality it is much better?
- Secondly why is it equal ?